# Parent of an id using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class="cdlButton" style="width:40px; float: left;">  // want this div element
     <div style="">
         <a id="changestatus" class="" onclick="changeWorkflowStatus()" href="#">
             <img id="" width="32px" height="32px" title="disable" alt="disable"  src="images/disable.png">
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want div with help of jquery 
Right now i am doing this way

```
 $("#changestatus ").parent().parent().addClass('disablecdlButton');
```

Is there any other way to get top div element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do various things here

```
$(".cdlButton").addClass('disablecdlButton');
$('#changestatus').closest('div.cdlButton').addClass('disablecdlButton');
$($('#changestatus').parents().get(-1)).addClass('disablecdlButton');
```

Answer (score 7):

```
$('#changestatus').closest('div.cdlButton').addClass('disablecdlButton');
```

> For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.

[**Official Document**](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

Comment: thanks for your reply. It is not necessary that cdlButton class is present. Still it is better option if class is present

Answer (score 1):

use  [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

> Description: For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.

```
$("#changestatus").closest("div.cdlButton").addClass('disablecdlButton');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
$("#changestatus ").parents(".cdlButton").addClass('disablecdlButton');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("#changestatus ").parents('div.cdlButton').addClass('disablecdlButton');
```

Comment: `.parent()` only finds an immediate parent, it doesn't go further up. In his case, it needs to go up 2 levels.

Comment: `.closest()` is better, don't you think? It stops as soon as it finds a match, rather than looking for additional matches further up the hierarchy.

Comment: Hey man, check it. It will work in his case.

http://jsfiddle.net/manumqln/WbnjJ/

Comment: I didn't say it wouldn't work, I just wondered why you think this is better than `.closest()`? They'll return the same thing if there's only one `cdlButton` in the ancestor chain, but `.parents()` has to do more work to find that out.

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/ngzAW/)**

Try this, `.parents('div').last()` will select the top most parent div element of the selected element , here it is `changestatus`

```
$("#changestatus ").parents('div').last().addClass('disablecdlButton');
```

Hope this helps,Thank you